# Pandas - Applying filter in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to perform a group by function in a Dataframe. I need two aggregations done, to find total count and find the count based on filtering of one column

```
product, count, type
prod_a,100,1
prod_b,200,2
prod_c,23,3
prod_d,23,1
```

I am trying to create a pivot of columns, `column 1` that has count of product sold and `column 2` that has count of products by `type 1`

```
       sold, type_1
prod_a,1,1
prod_b,1,0
prod_c,1,0
prod_d,1,1
```

I am able to get count of products sold but I am not sure how to apply filter and get the count of `prod_a` sold

```
df("product").agg({'count': [('sold', 'count')]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need count by only one condition like `type==1` then use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df2 = df.groupby("product").agg(sold = ('count','count'),
                                type_1= ('type', lambda x: (x == 1).sum()))
print (df2)

         sold  type_1
product              
prod_a      1       1
prod_b      1       0
prod_c      1       0
prod_d      1       1
```

For improve performance first create column and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df2 = (df.assign(type_1 = df['type'].eq(1).astype(int))
         .groupby("product").agg(sold = ('count','count'),
                                 type_1 = ('type_1','sum')))
```

---

For all combinations use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['product'], df['type']).add_prefix('type_')
df2 = df.groupby("product").agg(sold = ('count','count')).join(df1)
print (df2)
         sold  type_1  type_2  type_3
product                              
prod_a      1       1       0       0
prod_b      1       0       1       0
prod_c      1       0       0       1
prod_d      1       1       0       0
```